# '\n' in proxies in requests module of python

Tags: python, proxy, python-requests

I was using proxies in requests python and i came across this problem.

```
proxy = '159.197.128.8:3128'
response = s.get('http://ipv4.icanhazip.com', 
                 timeout=10,
                 proxies={"http": f"http://{proxy}", "https": f"http://{proxy}"},
                 headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/37.0.2062.94 Chrome/37.0.2062.94 Safari/537.36'})
print(response.content)
```

this code works perfectly fine.. also when i add a '\n' at the end of proxy..i.e

```
proxy=proxy+'\n'
```

it still works but adding two '\n' returns an error "Failed to parse"
I don't know how requests parses the proxies and why a '\n' at the end doesn't make a difference..please help me to understand this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just follow the traceback and look what's used to parse the proxy-url.

`requests` uses in the [`HTTPAdapter`.`get_connection()`](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/1466ad713cf84738cd28f1224a7ab4a19e50e361/requests/adapters.py#L305) `urllib3`'s [`parse_url`](https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/blob/e4f4e50e642e1a6fa6388c045829106a199d6944/src/urllib3/util/url.py#L386) method.
However, a regex is used to match the url (with [`re.match()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match)). The regex end with a `$`.

From the [related python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax):

> $
> Matches the end of the string **or just before the newline** at the end of the string, and in MULTILINE mode also matches before a newline. foo matches both ‘foo’ and ‘foobar’, while the regular expression foo$ matches only ‘foo’. More interestingly, searching for foo.$ in 'foo1\nfoo2\n' matches ‘foo2’ normally, but ‘foo1’ in MULTILINE mode; searching for a single $ in 'foo\n' will find two (empty) matches: one just before the newline, and one at the end of the string.

So the regex matches the string up to the end or up to the newline. Hence, the re more or less ignores the last new line.
But if you now have two line breaks in your proxy url, you have a multi-line-string and even if it ignores the last newline, there is still a newline that does not match the regex.

---

Here is a minimal example that has the same behavior:

```
>>> import re
>>> regex = re.compile(r'^\d$')  # matches exactly one digit
>>> print(re.match(regex, '1'))
<re.Match object; span=(0, 1), match='1'>
>>> print(re.match(regex, '1\n'))
<re.Match object; span=(0, 1), match='1'>
>>> print(re.match(regex, '1\n\n'))
None
```

Comment: Glad to help. Please see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: So sorry.. i know the drill.. i just forgot to accept the answer